# Location of roots of a truncated series

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Let $0<R<\pi/2$ be fixed. We want to show that for all sufficiently large $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the polynomial
$$ P_n(z):=1+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\ldots+\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ has no roots with absolute value less than $R$.

My instinct when I'm given a function and asked to show there are x many roots in a certain region (here the disk of radius $R$) is to use Rouché's Theorem. I haven't found a way to make that work here.

Alternatively, there may be something simple I'm overlooking. I know that $$\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$ If it weren't for the $(-1)^n$ term... Being given that $0<R<\pi/2$ makes me want to use something more like this (trig. functions).

Any hints to get the ball rolling would be appreciated!

Comment: what does $P_n(i\cdot z)$ look like?

Comment: @user8675309 ah, there it is. Thank you!!

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't like the $(-1)^n$, use $\cosh$.